# regex: match character in middle of url

Tags: regex

I have a URLs like these:

```
 http://dve.abc-de.com/some/fol/try/AB+C/folder/folder

 http://dve.abc-de.com/some/fol/try/try2/AB+C/bla/blu/
```

I need to match anything between http://vcs.abc-de.com/some/fol/ and /AB+C/. So my regex should return this:

```
try
try/try2
```

The first part `http://dve.abc-de.com/some/fol/` is always the same and the last part always begins with /AB+C and then something.

I've only managed to match http://vcs.abc-de.com/some/fol/ or /AB+C with lookbehinds and lookaheads, but never managed to match the string between those two.

I tried something like (I know this is wrong, but I can't reconstruct it anymore)

```
(?<=(http://vcs\.abc-de\.com/some/fol/)(.*?)(?=/AB+C*\))
```

How do I need to construct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `positive lookahead` and `positive lookbehind` like as

```
(?<=fol\/)(.*?)(?=\/AB\+C)/g
```

This'll get the value i.e. between `fol/` and `/AB+C` which is `try` and `try/try2` over given URL

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/jJ2bM6/3)

Answer (score 1):

Positive look ahead and positive look behind do your job

```
/(?<=fol\/).*(?=\/AB\+C\/)/g
```

or

```
/(?<=http\:\/\/dve\.abc-de\.com\/some\/fol\/).*(?=\/AB\+C\/)/g
```

**[Test regex here](https://regex101.com/r/gL1wU3/1)**

Answer (score 0):

This works in **JavaScript** Regex.

```
/.*?(try.*?)\/AB\+C/g
```

Example...

https://regex101.com/r/uK1hA6/1